# Invoke-WebRequest returning unexpected results for some addresses

Tags: powershell

I seem to be having issues with certain addresses when trying to process with `Invoke-WebRequest`

The address below is one example of a few that I have come across.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

(Invoke-WebRequest https://s3.amazonaws.com/lists.disconnect.me/simple_ad.txt).Content
(Invoke-WebRequest https://s3.amazonaws.com/lists.disconnect.me/simple_ad.txt).RawContent
```

The Content property seems to only return an Array of numbers. RawContent displays a result closer to what I would expect.

What is the reason for this?

Content

```
35
32
65
100
32
102
105
108
116
101
```

RawContent

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: juI0bRXZacf19D5/sjmsw53XudBjlbSYtO0XKVQP0N+dWXvixKoWs8mV8oF23SLt8iGjaE/CKco=
x-amz-request-id: 5B68B280AD366CDE
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 43642
Content-Type: 
Date: Fri, 13 Jul 2018 23:25:09 GMT
ETag: "0a43bd5ebd9b3e2ee08a205d163cb0ac"
Last-Modified: Wed, 09 Mar 2016 19:46:05 GMT
Server: AmazonS3

# Ad filter list by Disconnect
# License: GPLv3
# Contact: support [at] disconnect.me

htmlcontent
```

Comment: Curious, `Content` has a `Byte[]` type. Looks like a bug. Can't try it in the PS Core at the moment.

Comment: Weird, huh?! I hadn't actually thought to check the type, but, you're right! It's outputting it as `Byte[]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the headers, the Content Type is empty, therefore `Invoke-WebRequest` doesn't know what it's dealing with and treats the data as binary data (byte array).

```
(Invoke-WebRequest https://s3.amazonaws.com/lists.disconnect.me/simple_ad.txt).Headers

Key              Value
---              -----
Accept-Ranges    bytes
Content-Length   43642
Content-Type
Date             Sat, 14 Jul 2018 02:28:36 GMT
ETag             "0a43bd5ebd9b3e2ee08a205d163cb0ac"
Last-Modified    Wed, 09 Mar 2016 19:46:05 GMT
Server           AmazonS3
```

Whilst for example calling `Invoke-WebRequest` on this question:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51333965/invoke-webrequest-returning-unexpecte
d-results-for-some-addresses).Headers

Key                       Value
---                       -----
X-Frame-Options           SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Guid            9366c316-b9b3-467b-8911-b18bb4752e1c
Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15552000
Content-Security-Policy   upgrade-insecure-requests
Age                       0,0
Accept-Ranges             bytes,bytes
Content-Length            108783
Cache-Control             private
Content-Type              text/html; charset=utf-8
…
```

EDIT: If you want to overrule the content-type you could do something like this:

```
$url  = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/lists.disconnect.me/simple_ad.txt'
[System.Net.HttpWebRequest]$req = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url) -as [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]
[System.Net.HttpWebResponse]$resp = $req.getResponse()
$respStream = $resp.getResponseStream()
$sr = new-object IO.StreamReader($respStream)
$result = $sr.ReadToEnd()
$resp.Close()
```

Comment: Yes, but this is still inconsistent. For example, `Invoke-RestMethod https://s3.amazonaws.com/lists.disconnect.me/simple_ad.txt` returns string.

Comment: That's probably because Invoke-RestMethod expects a text (json) response and therefore always defaults to string. If you call `Invoke-RestMethod https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/putty-0.70.tar.gz` which is binary, the result is also a String.

Comment: Just tested it with PS Core and observed the same behavior. I think you're right about the cause, but I still can't fathom why `Content` is bytes and `RawContent` is string. Should be vice versa imo.

Comment: Ah - I see. Is there any way to tell Invoke-Webrequest what content type to expect? I tried using the `-ContentType` parameter but it still returns a byte array.

Comment: @mmotti see Edit for example of how to "overrule" Content Type

Comment: I just Invoked a Webrequest on a different server, and got returned a byte array via .content object. 
Got html data via .rawcontent though, but also includes headers. Anyone know how to just retrieve content via Invoke-WebRequest without -outfile ?